# unable to call onDrawerOpened and onDrawerClosed

Tags: android, eclipse

So, i was trying to create my app's navigation drawer, and i don't know why i can't call the public void `onDrawerOpened`, it just showing an error said `void is an invalid type for the variable onDrawerOpened` when i type it manually

so here's my `NavigationDrawerFragment.java` code

```
package id.WKKR.ktcafe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container,
                false);

    }

    public void setUp(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout,
                toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        {
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

        };
    }
}
```

thanks for anyone who help.

(edited)

so here's my mainactivity.java (called MenuUtama.java)

```js
► ► package id.WKKR.ktcafe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MenuUtama extends ActionBarActivity{

 Toolbar toolbar;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_utama);
  
  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  
  NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
  drawerFragment.setUp((DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),toolbar);


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_utama, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "This Is " + item.getTitle() + " Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return true;
  }
  
  if (id == R.id.bill) {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, BillTagihanAnda.class));
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override onDrawerOpened and onDrawerClosed methods. Add @override annotation or implement as shown below:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerlayout, toolBar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

                        };
```

Change the setup method in activity to:

```
NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
```

setup method in fragment include id fragment as said in one of my comments.

Comment: already add the @Override, but the error still remain, when i pointed my cursor on super.onDrawerOpened, it said "The method onDrawerOpened(View) is undefined for the type Fragment", is the problem because i'm extending fragment?

Comment: Even I have extended fragment and it works fine for me.  Please upload the complete code of fragment.

Comment: Try using the following method for setup:

 public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerlayout, final Toolbar toolBar) {

Comment: i've add my main activity, please take a look

Comment: do  not add it in answer edit the question and post it in question.

Comment: You need to add one more parameter in your setUp method of fragment and activity.

Comment: ok, i'll just try it, i'll post my answer if i figure it out, thanks anyway.

Comment: i finally find the problem, thanks for your help Keshav.

Comment: I have mentioned even that in my answer check. Any way cool that you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, my solution was the following:

1 - Create instance of: DrawerListener

```
DrawerLayout.DrawerListener acc = new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        // Action to onDrawerSlider
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {
        // Action to onDrawerOpened
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {
        // Action to onDrawerClosed
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
        // Action to onDrawerStateChanged
    }
};
```

2 - Set Listener to DrawerLayout Object:

```
mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(acc);
```

Answer (score 0):

hye Keshav, thanks for your help before, now i can figure it out why i can't use the onDrawerOpened before, kinda silly mistake, i accidentally put the semi-colon after the parentheses without knowing.

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout,
                toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
                            //here is my problem, i put the semi-colon after parentheses
                     {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setUp(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout,
            toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
    // you just need to remove the semicolon here
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: please, edit your answer to provide more information about your code.